# Magento 2 : How to create multiple shipping label with single order in UPS

Tags: magento2, shipping, ups, labels

I am using UPS shipping method. Scenario is :

Suppose order id #123 has 5 items of a product. When clicking on create shipping label button It should create 5 different shipping label within a single package.

What should be my approach? Please suggest